# How to Read and Write to a csv file in Android?

Tags: android, opencsv

I want to store 8 integers into a .csv file(the filename will be taken as an input from a EditText) and retrieve them when I want to.

Comment: Tutorial: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/491823/Read-fWriteplusCSVplusinplusplusAndroid

Comment: where is the question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the filename you can use this:

```
EditText fileNameEdit= (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.fileName);
String fileName = fileNameEdit.getText().toString();
```

Then write the file on disk:

```
try {
    String content = "Separe here integers by semi-colon";
    File file = new File(fileName +".csv");
    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {
       file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(content);
    bw.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

To read the file:

```
BufferedReader br = null; 
try {
  String sCurrentLine;
  br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName+".csv"));
  while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
  try {
     if (br != null)br.close();
  } catch (IOException ex) {
     ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

Then to have the Integers you can use split function:

```
String[] intArray = sCurrentLine.split(";");
```

Comment: How do I mention the entire file name. I tried mentioning "/storage/sdcard0/test"in the EditText but it always goes to the catch block. Do I need to add Permission WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the AndroidManifest.xml ? Please help. Thanks.

Comment: EDIT : Done! I just had to add the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Opencsv doesn't work on Android due to JDK issue.

> If you see simular to the following:
>
> 05-04 16:13:31.821 25829-25829/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION:
>   main Process: com.example.pk.opencsvpoc, PID: 25829
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Ljava/beans/Introspector;
>
> It is because Android only ported over a subset of java.beans into its
>   version of java. You can see a list of what is support at
>   https://developer.android.com/reference/java/beans/package-summary
>
> There are plans to switch over to reflection in opencsv 5.0 but I
>   doubt it will remove all our dependencies on java.beans. For now the
>   best suggestion for opencsv is to steer clear of the com.opencsv.bean
>   classes until Android fully supports java.beans or we are successful
>   in removing java.beans.
>
> Another possibility is to try another csv library. I checked apache
>   commons csv and super-csv and apache does not convert to beans but
>   super-csv does using only reflection.

Source: https://sourceforge.net/p/opencsv/wiki/FAQ/#getting-noclassdeffounderror-when-using-android

Answer (score 0):

CSV is normal text file, where values are divided by character ";" so, you can write it using BufferedWriter for example.

[BufferedWriter](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)